# Annoying error dialog box when eclipse output-console scrolls. What's causing it?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

When I run python scripts in Eclipse with Pydev - after a few seconds I get an eclipse Error dialog.

The window title is "Multiple Problems have occurred".

The box has a red X icon, adjacent to an error message "An internal error has occurred"

The list of error windows all have the text "Reveal End of Document". If I click on details I get the follow-on message

```
An internal error has occurred.
39
```

This problem seems to be related to the console. I've noticed that the scroll-bar is missing. I can sometimes scroll using the arrow keys, however scrolling occasionally causes the console area to mess up. I've googled that "Reveal End of Document" is supposed to be an exclipse IDE function which ought to cause a console to jump to the end.

Does anybody have an idea what might be going on? How can I fix this problem? It's really annoying.

Using Eclipse 3.6 on an up to date Sun JDK with Pydev plugin on Windows XP 32 bit.

Comment: This seems to be an Eclipse 3.6+ problem: I have the same thing, but am _not_ using PyDev. I have a nagging suspicion it's related to maven 3.

Comment: Yes, this bug seems to be fixed.

Comment: @Salim, it's still happening in 3.7 Indigo SR1 (20110916-0149), and appears to be a generic issue with Console (fixed-width) and unrelated to PyDev, or probably Maven either. (If you're claiming it's fixed please give us a specific version and build number?)

Comment: This is not related to Windows nor Pydev, I got the same on Linux using J2EE Indigo. However, I was logging damn long things (JSON) and used fixed width font.

Answer (score 18):

This seems to be related to [Eclipse Bug 243877 - IOConsole Updater error with long output lines](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=243877)

I am not using Pydev but I have been getting a lot of these "Reveal End of Document" popups and "org.eclipse.text" exceptions.

As mentioned in the bug report, it is directly related to the "Fixed width console" check box in Eclipse Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console.  When I checked the box and got too long message in my console, the exceptions flooded in.  As soon as I unchecked the box, it stopped.

Can't believe its still here in Indigo.

Comment: I suspect there are several distinct ways of tickling this bug. My case had the same cause and workaround as stridge's  (I use Indigo SR1, 20110916-0149, currently using it for Java not PyDev). Disabling fixed width console is an ugly workaround not a fix.

Comment: The same error happens if you have Word Wrap enabled.

Answer (score 5):

Just Uncheck **Fixed width console**.

Yes, this answer sounds weird, But it worked for me.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

See [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323306) which looks related.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: Closing all windows and views.
Right click on a source tab -> Close All. Do the same for Views. Re-run application.  Console automatically opens with output with no annoying error popup.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when your program exceeding the console width.
If you clear the console, the message box stop.
Right click and clear console (also when it's running).